# React on Express Server. Heroku deploy

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I wrote client side in React/Redux that is sending requests to Express App and express sends back the response with content from database. I want to deploy it to Heroku but I ve got a problem - I don't know how to do this. Locally I ran React on 8080port and server on 3000. Do I have to run client side(React) from Express App or run two scripts in one time(Express app and bundled react) ? I render content only on client side and express only takes request and sends response.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/alanbsmith/react-node-example?

Comment: Thanks i will take a look. I checked only more advanced code on github and get a litlle confused.

Comment: Thanks very much. I know everything :)